# Declaring an Opaleye table without using TemplateHaskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, opaleye

The [`opaleye` basic tutorial](https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/blob/master/Doc/Tutorial/TutorialBasic.lhs) gives an example on how to use user defined types in record types and queries:

```
data Birthday' a b = Birthday { bdName :: a, bdDay :: b }
type Birthday = Birthday' String Day
type BirthdayColumn = Birthday' (Column PGText) (Column PGDate)

birthdayTable :: Table BirthdayColumn BirthdayColumn
birthdayTable = table "birthdayTable"
    (pBirthday Birthday { bdName = tableColumn "name"
                        , bdDay  = tableColumn "birthday" })
```

Function `pBirthday` is generated using `TemplateHaskell`:

```
 $(makeAdaptorAndInstance "pBirthday" ''Birthday')
```

Where `makeAdaptorAndInstance` is a defined in [`Data.Functor.Product.TH`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/product-profunctors-0.6.3.1/docs/Data-Profunctor-Product-TH.html).

I would like to avoid using `TemplateHaskell`. The `opaleye` tutorial simply refers to the documentation of `Data.Functor.Product.TH`, which only explains that the instances generated by `makeAdaptorAndInstance` will be:

```
instance (ProductProfunctor p, Default p a a', Default p b b', Default p c c')
  => Default p (Birthday a b c) (Birthday a' b' c')
```

and `pBirthday` will have the type:

```
pBirthday :: ProductProfunctor p =>
    Birthday (p a a') (p b b') (p c c') -> p (Birthday a b c) (Birthday a' b' c')
```

But I cannot find any information on how to fill implement these functions by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHC has a [`-ddump-splices` option](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/debugging.html#dumping-out-compiler-intermediate-structures) to see the code generated with TH. I think that should be useful as it probably doesn't look too bad. (With `-ddump-to-file` and `-dumpdir` to control the output location.)

Here's one way to write it:

```
instance (ProductProfunctor p, Default p a a', Default p b b') => Default p (Birthday' a b) (Birthday' a' b') where
  def :: p (Birthday' a b) (Birthday' a' b')
  def = pBirthday (Birthday def def)


pBirthday :: ProductProfunctor p =>
  Birthday' (p a a') (p b b') -> p (Birthday a b) (Birthday a' b')
pBirthday (Birthday pa pb) =
  Birthday `rmap` lmap bdName pa **** lmap bdDay pb
  -- It generalizes the applicative construct
  --   "Birthday <$> pa <*> pb"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! After looking submitting my question I realized the tutorial referred to an old version of the documentation. In the [newest version of `product-profuctors`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/product-profunctors-0.8.0.3/docs/Data-Profunctor-Product-TH.html) this is also explained.

Comment: @DamianNadales I pushed this to improve the situation https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/commit/ddcee2f2ba0d20ab7f8e1d2bf09e940d23f04942